# jQuery nstSlider right-to-left

Tags: jquery, html, slider, rangeslider

I am using jQuery nstSlider (http://lokku.github.io/jquery-nstslider/) for a direction - rtl page. I could not find any support for rtl in their documentation.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Tried transform scaleX(_1), but  dragging works in opposite direction